# Adding and removing class in cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create something like a carousel, adding and removing an element specific class

```
<div class="advantages-slider">
<ul class="advantages-list">
    <li class="visible-adv">
        <img src="http://heidel.tw1.ru/test3/img/advantage_5.png" alt="" style="top: 11px; left: 12px;" />
        <div class="advantage-item-title">test</div>
        <div class="advantage-item-text">test</div>
    </li>
    <li class="visible-adv main-adv">
        <img src="http://heidel.tw1.ru/test3/img/advantage_4.png" alt="" style="top: 11px; left: 2px;" />
        <div class="advantage-item-title">test</div>
        <div class="advantage-item-text">test</div>
    </li>
    <li class="visible-adv">
        <img src="http://heidel.tw1.ru/test3/img/advantage_3.png" alt="" style="left: 2px;" />
        <div class="advantage-item-title">test</div>
        <div class="advantage-item-text">test</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://heidel.tw1.ru/test3/img/advantage_2.png" alt="" style="top: 11px; left: 10px;" />
        <div class="advantage-item-title">test</div>
        <div class="advantage-item-text">test</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://heidel.tw1.ru/test3/img/advantage_1.png" alt="" style="top: 11px; left: 5px;" />
        <div class="advantage-item-title">test</div>
        <div class="advantage-item-text">test</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

my script

```
$.fn.toggle_class_3 = function () {
var lis = this.find('li'),
    visibleLis = this.find('li.visible-adv'),
    len = lis.length,
    i = 0; // initialize pointer

setInterval(function () {
    visibleLis.slice(i, i + 1).animate({
        opacity: 0,
        width: 0,
        top: '50%',
        'left': '-50%'
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('visible-adv').css({
                'top': '50%',
                    'left': '50%'
            });
        }
    });

    lis.slice( i + 3, i + 4).animate({
        opacity: 1,
        width: '274px',
        height: 'auto',
        left: 0,
        top: 0
    }, {
        duration: 200,
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
            $(this).addClass('visible-adv');
        }
    });

    i = (i + 1) % len;
}, 2000);

return this;
};

$('.advantages-list').toggle_class_3();
```

The class `.visible-adv'` is originally added to the first three elements, then I remove it from the first element and add to the fourth and so on. But I can not get this to happen in cycle. Is there any way to make it work?

http://jsfiddle.net/YjpFL/1/

Comment: use toggleClass instead of removeClass and addClass

Comment: I don't need toggleClass, I need to remove class from the first element and add it to the forth element, class for the second and the third element stayes THE SAME!

Comment: Hi, I tried to solve this. please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/YjpFL/3/